# IntelliJ debugger is connected to Firebase local emulator but doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, emulation, firebase-tools

I've been at this for days on and off.  Read through and followed all threads on the subject i could find but still can't get this to work.

I'm trying to debug Firebase functions locally in IntelliJ IDE.  Here's the output of start command.

```
**firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions**

> bear@paw:~/dev/test-cloud-functions$ firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions \
> i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore\
> ⚠  functions: You are running the Functions emulator in debug mode (port=9229). This means that functions will execute in sequence rather than in parallel.\
> ⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, database, hosting, pubsub, storage\
> i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log\
> ✔  firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150.\
> i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log \
> i  functions: Watching "/home/bear/dev/test-cloud-functions/functions" for Cloud Functions...\
> ✔  functions: Using node@16 from host.\
> ✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: .\
>  Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/8aef43e5-94cb-4d79-b178-92db4ba380c9
>  For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
> i  functions: Watching "/home/bear/dev/test-cloud-functions/mod" for Cloud Functions...
> ✔  functions: Using node@16 from host.\
> ✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: processTransaction, testFunction.\
> ✔  functions[europe-west1-processTransaction]: firestore function initialized.\
> ✔  functions[europe-west1-testFunction]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/testproject/europe-west1/testFunction).\
>  Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use
>
>┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
>│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
>│ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000/               │
>└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
>
>┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
>│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
>├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
>│ Functions │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions │
>├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
>│ Firestore │ 127.0.0.1:8080 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore │
>└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
>  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400\
>  Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150\
>
>Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.\
> 
>  Debugger attached.\  
>  Checking ip address\
>  Outbound IP address is: 124.120.192.159\

> ✔  functions: Using node@16 from host.\
> ✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: processTransaction, testFunction.\
>  Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use\
> ✔  functions: Using node@16 from host.\
> ✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: processTransaction, testFunction.\
>  Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use\
>  Checking ip address\
>  Outbound IP address is: 124.120.192.159\
>  Debugger ending on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/8aef43e5-94cb-4d79-b178-92db4ba380c9\
>  For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector\
>  Debugger attached.
```

The debugger configuration is set attached to Chrome/Node on port 9229 and appears to be working fine.   However when i set breakpoints and call the testFunction by opening a browser to http://127.0.0.1:5001/test-project/europe-west1/testFunction  the function runs and shows its output of external ip address without stopping at the breakpoints. Is there a special way to call the Firebase emulator function in order to envoke the debugger? What am i missing?    Please help.

Answer (score 1):

From https://medium.com/@david_shortman/build-and-debug-firebase-functions-in-vscode-73efb76166cf, *Using Firebase Functions from a Webpage in Javascript* section I can see that such functions have to be debugged in a different way; you likely have to use **JavaScript Debug** run configuration (see *Debugging a Webpage with Chrome debugger* at the bottom of the page). Didn't try it myself though. Can you check if you can debug your functions in Chrome Dev Tools, for example? if it works, then debugging with **JavaScript Debug** run configuration should work as well

I'd also suggest  asking a question at [Firebase Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk)

Comment: Thank you for the response and the link but the medium article is a bit out of date since Firebase had introduced the --inspect-functions option to firebase-tools since it was written.  So the setup now is much simpler than the article describes. I tried to run it that way but unfortunately with the same result.